# jQuery with Google maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I'd like to use jQuery with Google maps. I'm trying to replicate [this example](http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-google-maps-streetview.html). Below is given the code that I'm using. The problem is that the map does not appear on my web-page. It's just blank. What's the case?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.ui.map.js"></script>

    <div id="fragment-4">
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#map_canvas').gmap().bind('init', function(evt, map) {
            $('#map_canvas').gmap('microformat', '.vevent', function(result, item, index) {
                var clone = $(item).clone().addClass('ui-dialog-vevent');
                clone.append('<div id="streetview{0}" class="streetview"></div>'.replace('{0}', index));
                var lat = result.location[0].geo[0].latitude['value-title']; 
                var lng = result.location[0].geo[0].longitude['value-title'];
                $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', { 
                        'bounds':true, 
                        'position': new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng), 
                        'title': result.summary,  
                    }, 
                function(map, marker) {
                    $(item).find('.summary').click( function() {
                        $(marker).triggerEvent('click');
                        return false;
                    }); 
                }).click(function() {
                    map.panTo( $(this).get(0).getPosition());
                    $(clone).dialog({ 
                        'modal': true, 
                        'width': 530, 
                        'title': result.summary, 
                        'resizable': false, 
                        'draggable': false 
                    });
                    $('#map_canvas').gmap('displayStreetView', 'streetview{0}'.replace('{0}', index), { 
                        'position': $(this).get(0).getPosition() 
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
        </script>
                <div id="map_canvas">

    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Do you have an actual div with id 'map_canvas' where the map will be drawn?

Comment: Try to add your javascript within `ready` callback-> `$(document).ready(function(){/*Script here*/});`

Comment: Please look at the updated code. I included your suggestions, but still it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pure JavaScript for this.
JQUERY is not the best choice in this case.
I have developed a huge API to overlay vector blueprints over Google Maps and I can tell you that even though it might be a bit more to type it is way better to just use JavaScript.
Do not over complicate things and as M1ke said always keep your console open when working with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that's your entire code it could be a number of things:

- Have you got that script file on line 3 in the correct folder (check your console)
- You're targeting #map_canvas but that element doesn't exist.
- Having copied the script you need to pass options to the gmap() method or it throws an error.

Best thing would be to check your JavaScript console (Ctrl + Shift + J in Chrome, download Firebug if you're using Firefox) to see the error trace and fix from there.

Also including your script inside a div isn't necessary - the only use for giving the script awareness of a calling element would be if you were using document write, and as you're using jQuery I doubt this will become the case.